# PostgreSQL get results in current time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

as said in the title I would like to have a query that returns the value of the time stamp in my current time zone (even according summer time!).

*my_table* is:

```
|timestamp|name|value|property1|property2|
|---|---|---|---|---|
|2021-08-01 00:00:00+00|10|0.44|0|0|
|2021-08-01 00:05:00+00|15|0.76|0|0|
|2021-08-01 00:10:00+00|12|0.28|0|0|
```

*(Don't ask me why I cannot put this table directly in markdown...prob cause the dates)*

Now for example if I have to select the 24h corresponding to the entire day in my time zone at the moment my solution is:

```
SELECT timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CEST',name,value
FROM my_table
WHERE name IN (10,11,12)
AND timestamp BETWEEN '2021-08-01 00:00:00+02' AND '2021-08-02 00:00:00+02' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

As you can see there is a problems here:

- I have to specify every time if I is CEST or CET (now is CEST here)
- and then I have to add +02 at the end of the dates (or +01 in CET)

**There is a way to avoid this conceptual repetition??** any suggestion even to improve the query is appreciated

the command `SELECT version();` gives me back `PostgreSQL 12.7`

Comment: What is the actual data type for the `timestamp` field( not a good idea to use a type as a field name)?

Comment: Is a TIMESTAMPTZ! yes probably not a good idea...nice call ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your session's timezone appropriately.

```
set timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin';

select '2021-08-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2021-08-01 02:00:00+02

select '2021-12-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2021-12-01 01:00:00+01

select '2021-08-01 00:00:00'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2021-08-01 00:00:00+02
```

What is your session timezone set to now?

Comment: my database is in utc and my session too but the problem is that if I want today's data(I am in 'Europe/Berlin') for example I have to add +02 when I select the range. can I avoid it in the between operator? Switch the session btw is a good idea

Comment: Setting the session timezone should make the BETWEEN just work.  The +2 (or +1 when not summer) gets added automatically if nothing is specified on the input, as the 3rd example shows.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your answer...It works! This is the complete query: set timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin';
SELECT timestamp::timestamptz,name,value
FROM my_table
WHERE name IN (10,11,12)
AND timestamp BETWEEN '2021-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-08-02 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC. Porb is better add it to the answer.